# login page that works with auth0, authResult return null

Tags: javascript, authentication

I am trying to add auth0 to my JS application, with this tutorial - https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vanillajs/01-login#handle-authentication-tokens
The authResult in parseHase return null (err also return null).

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess `parseHash`

Comment: Have you got any `err` in console or alert?

Comment: No errors. Just return null

Comment: is there any connection attempted to a server? maybe a timeout happening? maybe you do not have correct credentials or at all?

Comment: I connect to the <mydomain>auth0.com, pass the login and see the new page I 
 defined in the redirectUri field. I just dont see the tokens after that and get null instead.